# Verifying toast message in Tosca

Tags: testing, web-applications, automation, tosca

I scanned toast message object in Tosca and I used it in my test cases.that same popup will appear twice in the flow.
First time Tosca is able to validate the popup but for second one I'm getting error as container was not found.

If I run the 2nd popup flow seperately Tosca is able to validate it.but if i run the whole flow it fails with the mentioned error.

Need some help here .....

I want Tosca to identify and validate the toast popup without any error

Comment: I think you should try scan two separate modules, even if it looks like the same popup maybe there are some differencies.

Comment: Check the second toast manually, does it have the same identifiers and values for the identifires?

Comment: They are same.the solution I found and it worked. I added page refresh before performing second functionality now the validation is working fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Is both of your Toasters are same? If yes try the below, if no capture or Manually add the parameter with the right module attribute properties directly.

Apply Exists = True, WaitOn for the toaster message, the cause of the issue would be the toaster appears faster then the script executes or vice versa, to balance the Application performance and TOSCA Execution Performance, Add waitOn's for the control that you are verifying for.